# Heavy-handed question locking?

Tags: discussion

The question [Does this sentence seem weird grammatically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599138/does-this-sentence-seem-weird-grammatically?noredirect=1#comment1508288_599138) was summarily locked, and the couple of comments I'd posted (primarily in order to advertise and justify my vote to migrate to ELL) were moved to chat.

It does rather look as if the (new) user was going to string things out, somewhat pointlessly asking what I thought of his *exact* example when I'd already described the construction under consideration as *"valid", but "formal, literary"*. I probably wouldn't have replied to that - or if I *had*, I might have just said it's an (Off Topic) matter of opinion and left it at that.

I don't feel very strongly about which site the question should be on. I think the *exact* thing being asked (Is this construction weird?) is definitely something for ELL (where I would simply advise learners *not* to use it themselves).

But potentially some users here on ***ELU*** might have much more to say about the syntax involved. That's why in my first comment I gave a similar example where only negating ***not*** was moved from its default position, rather than other parts of an adjectival phrase. I don't know how to accurately summarize the syntactic principle and terminology, but I can certainly see that an answer addressing *those* issues would be a good fit on ELU (but it's probably not something most *learners* would need to concern themselves with, as indicated above).

Cutting to the chase, I think at least the first few comments should have stayed on the main site. If only to encourage others to consider voting to migrate *and/or* to address the broader issue of "syntactic inversion" in related contexts such as my ***not*** example.

Comment: I suppose closing this as a duplicate might seem heavy-handed. But the linked question is virtually the same and has the same answer. Answers do not go in comments.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for the response, anyway. But the question has now been *closed* rather than migrated, which seems even more heavy-handed to me. I think *Does this sound weird?* questions are in principle Off Topic on both sites - but as set out above, I think learners could benefit from being told that although the construction is perfectly *valid*, they should probably avoid using it themselves unless and until they've encountered it so often they know how to use it without thinking too much. AND if it stays here, I'm sure someone could tell us (me! :) much more about exactly how it works.

Comment: ...so I might forget about my "migrate" vote, and vote to reopen on ELU purely to seek further enlightenment for myself on exactly which kinds of "relocation of words within an utterance" are normally considered acceptable.

Comment: Ho hum. I ***can't add a comment*** explaining my re-open vote with a link to this meta question. The OP has probably got everything he needed from the responses now moved to chat, so if I can't find a "possible duplicate", I might just edit the question to make it more suitable for ELU as implied above.